# Artifactory - Bad header value content-type of pom.xml from repo.spring.io

Tags: spring, http-headers, artifactory, mime-types, sonatype

We are not able to download pom.xml files from repo.spring.io with our updated 'Sonatype Nexus Repository' due to an invalid header value for content-type returned by artifactory.

> 2024-02-14 06:46:54,705+0000 WARN  [xxx]  UNKNOWN
> org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageTxImpl - An exception
> occurred determining the content type of asset
> org/springframework/ai/spring-ai-openai-spring-boot-starter/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/spring-ai-openai-spring-boot-starter-0.8.0-20240214.061929-153.pom
> in repository maven_proxy_repo.spring.io-snapshot
>
> 2024-02-14 06:46:54,708+0000 WARN  [xxx]  UNKNOWN
> org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.handlers.ExceptionHandler - Invalid
> content: GET
> /org/springframework/ai/spring-ai-openai-spring-boot-starter/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/spring-ai-openai-spring-boot-starter-0.8.0-20240214.061929-153.pom:
> org.sonatype.nexus.repository.InvalidContentException: Content type
> could not be determined: **application/x-maven-pom xml**

I don't know if this is a bug in Jfrog-Artifactory or a bad configuration by repo.spring.io

```
curl -L -v "https://repo.spring.io/artifactory/snapshot/org/springframework/ai/spring-ai-openai-spring-boot-starter/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/spring-ai-openai-spring-boot-starter-0.8.0-20240216.110642-162.pom" > /dev/null
```

< "content-type: application/x-maven-pom xml"

Note that there is a space in the value.  According to RFC, that is not legal:
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html

According to Nexus Documentation, the correct value must be "content-type: application/x-maven-pom"

see : [Overriding-or-changing-default-MIME-types-for-artifact-downloads](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465408-Overriding-or-changing-default-MIME-types-for-artifact-downloads)

Since the header value does not respect the RFC, we cannot override configuration of our Nexus Repository to accept a such mime-type value

Edit : the milestone repository (https://repo.spring.io/artifactory/milestone/) send a valid header "content-type: application/x-maven-pom+xml"